# Is there a way to patch '---' separated multi document kubernetes yaml files?

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml

I've been using patches to change values in k8s, but after running kustomize build this time I have multiple result files. Is there a way to select which file to modify?

Lets say for example I have a kustomize build output like this one

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
(...)
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
(...)
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
(...)
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
(...)
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
(...)
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
      (...)
    spec:
      containers:
      (...)
      initContainers:
      - args:
        (...)
        image: <some value>
        (...)
---
apiVersion:
(...)
---
apiVersion:
(...)
---
apiVersion:
(...)
```

I try to change the value of the image field like this

```
- op: replace
  path: /4/spec/template/spec/initContainers/0/image
  value: <some value>
```

But I don't see the value change. As if the path is the wrong one. Is this something I'm doing wrong? or is it a limitation of the patch mechanism?

Comment: `kubectl patch` is only applicable to resources that are deployed on a cluster. You should use kustomize itself to change the values in YAML files before they're applied to the cluster.